# 'import' does not name type ERROR

Tags: arduino-uno, accelerometer, gyroscope, compilation-errors, imu

I am working with a group of people on an arduino controlled BB8 robot. We are using an IMU unit (accelerometer+gyroscope). I found a processing example for the IMU unit we are using. The code is shown below. I am getting an error "'import' does not name type". I know programming but I am not very familiar with arduino. Can anyone help me?

```
import processing.serial.*;

Serial myPort;  // Create object from Serial class

final String serialPort = "/dev/tty.usbmodem621"; // replace this with your serial port. On windows you will need something like "COM1".

float [] q = new float [4];
float [] hq = null;
float [] Euler = new float [3]; // psi, theta, phi

int lf = 10; // 10 is '\n' in ASCII
byte[] inBuffer = new byte[22]; // this is the number of chars on each line from the Arduino (including /r/n)

PFont font;

void setup() 
{
  size(800, 600, P3D);
  myPort = new Serial(this, serialPort, 115200);  

  font = createFont("Courier", 32); 


  /*
  float [] axis = new float[3];
   axis[0] = 0.0;
   axis[1] = 0.0;
   axis[2] = 1.0;
   float angle = PI/2.0;

   hq = quatAxisAngle(axis, angle);

   hq = new float[4];
   hq[0] = 0.0;
   hq[1] = 0.0;
   hq[2] = 0.0;
   hq[3] = 1.0;
   */

  delay(100);
  myPort.clear();
  myPort.write("1");
}


float decodeFloat(String inString) {
  byte [] inData = new byte[4];

  if (inString.length() == 8) {
    inData[0] = (byte) unhex(inString.substring(0, 2));
    inData[1] = (byte) unhex(inString.substring(2, 4));
    inData[2] = (byte) unhex(inString.substring(4, 6));
    inData[3] = (byte) unhex(inString.substring(6, 8));
  }

  int intbits = (inData[3] << 24) | ((inData[2] & 0xff) << 16) | ((inData[1] & 0xff) << 8) | (inData[0] & 0xff);
  return Float.intBitsToFloat(intbits);
}


void readQ() {
  if (myPort.available() >= 18) {
    String inputString = myPort.readStringUntil(lf);
    //print(inputString);
    if (inputString != null && inputString.length() > 0) {
      String [] inputStringArr = split(inputString, ",");
      if (inputStringArr.length >= 5) { // q1,q2,q3,q4,\r\n so we have 5 elements
        q[0] = decodeFloat(inputStringArr[0]);
        q[1] = decodeFloat(inputStringArr[1]);
        q[2] = decodeFloat(inputStringArr[2]);
        q[3] = decodeFloat(inputStringArr[3]);
      }
    }
  }
}


void buildBoxShape() {
  //box(60, 10, 40);
  noStroke();
  beginShape(QUADS);

  //Z+ (to the drawing area)
  fill(0,255,0);
  vertex(-30, -5, 20);
  vertex(30, -5, 20);
  vertex(30, 5, 20);
  vertex(-30, 5, 20);

  //Z-
  fill(0,0,255);
  vertex(-30, -5, -20);
  vertex(30, -5, -20);
  vertex(30, 5, -20);
  vertex(-30, 5, -20);

  //X-
  fill(255,0,0);
  vertex(-30, -5, -20);
  vertex(-30, -5, 20);
  vertex(-30, 5, 20);
  vertex(-30, 5, -20);

  //X+
  fill(255,255,0);
  vertex(30, -5, -20);
  vertex(30, -5, 20);
  vertex(30, 5, 20);
  vertex(30, 5, -20);

  //Y-
  fill(255,0,255);
  vertex(-30, -5, -20);
  vertex(30, -5, -20);
  vertex(30, -5, 20);
  vertex(-30, -5, 20);

  //Y+
  fill(0,255,255);
  vertex(-30, 5, -20);
  vertex(30, 5, -20);
  vertex(30, 5, 20);
  vertex(-30, 5, 20);

  endShape();
}


void drawCube() {  
  pushMatrix();
  translate(800/2, 600/2 + 50, 0);
  scale(5, 5, 5);

  // a demonstration of the following is at 
  // http://www.varesano.net/blog/fabio/ahrs-sensor-fusion-orientation-filter-3d-graphical-rotating-cube
  rotateZ(-Euler[2]);
  rotateX(-Euler[1]);
  rotateY(-Euler[0]);

  buildBoxShape();

  popMatrix();
}


void draw() {
  background(0,0,0);
  fill(255,255,255);

  readQ();

  if (hq != null) { // use home quaternion
    quaternionToEuler(quatProd(hq, q), Euler);
    text("Disable home position by pressing \"n\"", 20, 600 - 30);
  }
  else {
    quaternionToEuler(q, Euler);
    text("Point FreeIMU's X axis to your monitor then press \"h\"", 20, 600 - 30);
  }

  textFont(font, 20);
  textAlign(LEFT, TOP);
  text("Q:\n" + q[0] + "\n" + q[1] + "\n" + q[2] + "\n" + q[3], 20, 20);
  text("Euler Angles:\nYaw (psi)  : " + degrees(Euler[0]) + "\nPitch (theta): " + degrees(Euler[1]) + "\nRoll (phi)  : " + degrees(Euler[2]), 200, 20);

  drawCube();
}


void keyPressed() {
  if (key == 'h') {
    println("pressed h");

    // set hq the home quaternion as the quatnion conjugate coming from the sensor fusion
    hq = quatConjugate(q);
  }
  else if (key == 'n') {
    println("pressed n");
    hq = null;
  }
}

// See Sebastian O.H. Madwick report 
// "An efficient orientation filter for inertial and intertial/magnetic sensor arrays" Chapter 2 Quaternion representation

void quaternionToEuler(float [] q, float [] euler) {
  euler[0] = atan2(2 * q[1] * q[2] - 2 * q[0] * q[3], 2 * q[0]*q[0] + 2 * q[1] * q[1] - 1); // psi
  euler[1] = -asin(2 * q[1] * q[3] + 2 * q[0] * q[2]); // theta
  euler[2] = atan2(2 * q[2] * q[3] - 2 * q[0] * q[1], 2 * q[0] * q[0] + 2 * q[3] * q[3] - 1); // phi
}

float [] quatProd(float [] a, float [] b) {
  float [] q = new float[4];

  q[0] = a[0] * b[0] - a[1] * b[1] - a[2] * b[2] - a[3] * b[3];
  q[1] = a[0] * b[1] + a[1] * b[0] + a[2] * b[3] - a[3] * b[2];
  q[2] = a[0] * b[2] - a[1] * b[3] + a[2] * b[0] + a[3] * b[1];
  q[3] = a[0] * b[3] + a[1] * b[2] - a[2] * b[1] + a[3] * b[0];

  return q;
}

// returns a quaternion from an axis angle representation
float [] quatAxisAngle(float [] axis, float angle) {
  float [] q = new float[4];

  float halfAngle = angle / 2.0;
  float sinHalfAngle = sin(halfAngle);
  q[0] = cos(halfAngle);
  q[1] = -axis[0] * sinHalfAngle;
  q[2] = -axis[1] * sinHalfAngle;
  q[3] = -axis[2] * sinHalfAngle;

  return q;
}

// return the quaternion conjugate of quat
float [] quatConjugate(float [] quat) {
  float [] conj = new float[4];

  conj[0] = quat[0];
  conj[1] = -quat[1];
  conj[2] = -quat[2];
  conj[3] = -quat[3];

  return conj;
}
```

Comment: You can't put Processing code onto an Arduino.

Comment: While you could painfully translate this, what you probably want to do is find an Arduino library and/or example for the sensor chip you are using.

Comment: One of the most important things people have to realize when they program is that when an error occurs on a product, the chances of someone else having the same error and reporting that error on the internet is highly likely. Unless the product is brand new, there's no way that you would be the first one to encounter this error. Another important thing that new programmers should remember is that when they find code online, there's a tendency of the code not working. Henceforth, you need to debug and evaluate the code yourself.

Comment: Frankly this seems a rather harsh response to a relatively innocent and simple to explain mistake which could nonetheless be quite perplexing when encountered.  Let's not forget that Arduino has shared heritage with Processing and that they are sometimes spoken of together, despite having different syntax and targets.

Answer (score 2):

Processing code is intended to be run on a computer. You would use the [Processing IDE](https://processing.org/reference/environment/) to run this code.

The Arduino IDE is used to write, compile, and upload code to a microcontroller that you might have on an Arduino board. This is the cause of the error.